# Reduce Creation Time: NebulaLogger in a Scratch Org during CI

Tags: scratch-org, ci

We want to use NebulaLogger. We also have a CI job that creates a scratch org on a new Pull Request. Technically everything works fine. The only issue is the time it takes to create a scratch org ~40 mins (push + Nebula package install + tests run). This is very slow.

Is there a way to use NebulaLogger, but reduce time for Scratch Org creation?

Comment: Until Salesforce introduces Scratch Org Snapshots there is nothing you can do to improve this process. The push and install have to happen sequentially since only one deploy is allowed at a time... and obviously the test execution requires the deploys to have finished.

Comment: Oh, there is the option to use "scratch org pooling", as suggested by [dxatscale](https://docs.dxatscale.io/media-library/knowledge-articles/scratch-org-pooling-for-ci). Obviously this uses your daily and active scratch org allowances in advance and you may find you are wasting numbers of scratch orgs if the pipeline doesn't actually use them.